# How to solve an equation including a convolution integral in python?

Tags: python, scipy, convolution, differential-equations, odeint

I am trying to solve Cummins' equation:
[image: Cummins' equation]

In this equation, M, A_inf and C are (n, n) constant matrices, F^exc is a time-dependent vector of length n, and K is a so-called 'Impulse Response Function' which associates an (n, n) matrix to each time step. I would like to solve for X which is a displacement vector of size n.

I tried the usual python method used to get ODE solutions, which is to say I tried to create a function where the derivative of x is equal to a function of x, then use scipy.integrate.odeint to solve, however this does not work because of the convolution component that needs preceding values of X to be calculated.
Can anyone help please?